# Strange sequence of upvotes

Tags: discussion, moderators, up-votes, serial-voting

About 10 minutes into the "day", I started receiving a [long sequence of single votes on questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recent/742?startdate=2011-02-20%2000:00:00z&enddate=2011-02-20%2023:59:59z&tab=reputation#tab-top) There are 28 upvotes over a period of 2-3 minutes. Moreover, they occurred on my answers in almost precisely the inverse order in which they appear in my profile when listed by number of votes (a few answers seem to have been skipped).  Then they stopped shortly after they hit my reputation cap.

Not that I mind getting votes, but this seems almost like "spam upvoting", someone who decided they wanted to 'reward me' by upvoting my answers, regardless of what those answers say. If it was indeed one person, there is simply no way that those votes can reflect an appreciation of the answers themselves, because there is no way the answers were read in those two minutes.

I'm not really sure what I'm trying to say; except that it all makes me feel rather uneasy. If the moderators could check if it was indeed a single person just "serial-voting", then perhaps that person could be contacted. I don't think serial up-voting is any better than serial down-voting.

Or maybe I'm being overly sensitive; it just seems like I didn't really "earn" those votes.

**Update.** The votes (and rep) seem to have now "gone away."

Comment: You could shed the rep by offering a bounty on some interesting (new) question. The site benefits from highly exposed good questions.

Comment: @Bill: The rep has gone away after a recomp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, the daily vote anomaly script will remove any statistically anomalous vote patterns that are far outside statistical norms. This will happen every 24 hours.

Comment: I'm okay with these votes going away (after all, I posted here drawing attention to them); but if it was someone who thought he was "doing me a favor", I would hope he is notified that this isn't the way to go about it...

Comment: One of the up-votes happened to tip a question over the threshold for a badge ("Good Answer" to be precise). I assume the badge will go away as well, probably next "day" or so?

Comment: @arturo no, this means you won't get the next badge of the same type, to keep counts in sync. Badges are almost never removed.

Comment: Is it the next badge of the same type associated to *any* answer, or rather, if that answer gets that 25th vote later, then a new badge will not be generated? The latter seems reasonable, the former seems a bit weird.

Comment: The same thing just happened to me, including the "Nice answer" badge. Guess I'll enjoy it while it lasts!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's showing up in the catalog of suspicious vote patterns, and none of the people who have voted for you at least 28 times look particularly suspicious. It is possible this was just the system updating late on votes you had already received. I can trigger a rep recalc but I'm not sure if that would actually do anything.

Comment: Given the fact these are 28 of the 31 answers I have with most votes, and they were voted on in precisely the same order as they appear on my user page, it seems unlikely they would be late votes already received...

Comment: @Arturo: It seems that someone desired to bump you up to the highest rep user.